# Create SQL Server stored procedure to add movie to queue for customers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need some assistance on how to create a stored procedure for SQL Server so that when the stored procedure is executed, I can add a movie to the queue and that the newly added movie will be the next movie they receive. The other movies in the queue for the customer will be decremented (moved down on the list).

I have the following tables already created - work in progress.

- `Customer` - customer_ID (pk), first_name, last_name
- `Queue` - queue_ID (pk), customer_ID (fk), movie_ID (fK) -- need another column for priority?
- `Movie` - movie_ID (pk), movie_Title

If possible I would like to maintain one queue for all customers that rent movies.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: ...Nothing yet. Still thinking about how to approach it.

Comment: Whatever you meant to post in your answer comment - add to your main question instead.

Comment: I have not tried anything at the moment, because I don't know how to approach the process of being able to determine the proper code for the stored procedure.

Comment: Please elaborate by providing sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a Priority column as you suggested.  You could then do an UPDATE on the Queue table where the customer_ID (And [ReceivedDate] IS NULL flag to ignore processed data?) and increase all the Priority fields by 1.

1st: You would UPDATE Queue SET Priority=(Priority+1) WHERE customer_ID=@customerId
2nd: Insert the new record into Queue and set Priority=1